# I am having this error in flutter while using google map through dependency map_view kindly help me

Tags: flutter

The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version `1.3.10` and higher.

The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:

```
project ':map_view' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle plugin version that is supported in your project is **1.3.10** and higher, the plugin you are trying to install is using gradle **1.2.50** there for not supported. I suggest you find another plugin since the only [map view](https://pub.dev/packages/map_view) plugin i found states that is **discontinued**. I suggest when you pick a plugin to use to check how often it get updated and when the last update happent.

Comment: A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V